# In log file need to search specific Pattern for RC (return code) = 1-1000 if i find RC (return code) = 0 ignore and if its greater than 0 exit -1

Tags: powershell

In my log file i have Pattern

```
RC (return code) = 0 
RC (return code) = 1 
RC (return code) = 4
RC (return code) = 8
RC (return code) = 35
RC (return code) = 200
```

am using below command to search my string

```
if ( (Get-ChildItem c:\changedObject\changed\table | Select-String-Pattern 'RC \(return code\) = 4').ToString().Split("=")[1].Trim() -eq 0 ) {0} else {exit -1}
```

If my file don't have **RC (return code) = 4**  by command is not working

My requirement is

if i find **RC (return code) = 0** ignore and search further string match in the file and if i find > 0 as value for RC (return code) =  , print "Value is greater than 0"

Answer (score 2):

This should get useful information about your files:

```
Get-ChildItem c:\changedObject\changed\table | 
     Select-String -Pattern 'RC \(return code\) = (\d+)' |
        ForEach-Object {
            $_ | Select-Object FileName, Line, LineNumber, @{Label="ReturnCode";Expression = {$_.Matches.Groups[1].Value}}
        }
```

This will output a collection of objects you can further manipulate.  By itself, it will give you a table like this:

```
Filename   Line                     LineNumber  ReturnCode
--------   ----                     ----------  ----------
text1.txt  RC (return code) = 879            1  879       
text2.txt  RC (return code) = 2              1  2         
text3.txt  RC (return code) = 200            1  200
```

This will match any number (not just 1-1000), but I assume the actual number range isn't an issue.

If you want to use your original technique, then you need to modify it slightly:

```
if ((Get-ChildItem c:\changedObject\changed\table | 
     Select-String -Pattern 'RC \(return code\) = (\d+)') | 
        ForEach-Object{$_.Line.Split("=")[1].Trim() -eq "0"})
   {"zero"}else{"No zero"}
```

Though, all this tells you is at least one file contains 'RC (return code) = 0', but doesn't tell you which file or how many have that value.

**EDIT: Added modified code for updated requirements:**

As an example of how you can further manipulate the outoput of my first example, the following code will list only the highest (non-zero) return code found in each file:

```
Get-ChildItem .\test | 
     Select-String -Pattern 'RC \(return code\) = (\d+)' |
        ForEach-Object {
            $_ | Select-Object FileName, Line, LineNumber, @{label="ReturnCode";Expression = {$_.Matches.Groups[1].Value}}
        } | Where-Object {[int]$_.ReturnCode -gt 0} | 
                Group-Object FileName | 
                    ForEach-Object {$_.Group | Sort-Object ReturnCode -Descending | Select-Object -First 1 }
```

Comment: @ boxdag i update the my requirement, can you please help me on this

Comment: My original code example should output every RC found in every file.  I've added an example of how you might use this to find the highest code in each file.  I'll leave it to you to modify further to suit your particular situation.